# Can't get Tailwind CSS to work on my existing project in Intellij

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, tailwind-css

I am trying to add Tailwind CSS to my existing project. For now it's only a simple project with a log-in function, but before I implement the backend and database, I want to style it. I've followed the instructions here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation, but i know I'm missing something, but don't know what.

[Setup-picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixnYY.png)

Does someone have a clue?

Comment: the tailwind config is not on the root project folder. 
  Its in /server.

Comment: No, it is in the root project folder. /server only contains node_modules, package.json, package-lock.json and server.js

Comment: oh yeah! mb
there isn't any output.css in your project folder

Comment: Please make sure that [Tailwind CSS](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15321-tailwind-css) plugin is installed and enabled. (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.